# Change header menu login-logout without changing main menu

Tags: menus, headers

I'm trying to change the header menu, such that it looks different when it is logged in and logged out, without changing the main menu.

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
        $args['widget_nav_menu'] = 'menu 4';
    } else { 
        $args['widget_nav_menu'] = 'menu 3';
    } 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

This does the job to change the header menu, but it also changes the main menu. How do I get it to not change the main menu?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You should add a class to the header when the user is logged in, this way, only your css would have to change.

You can do it like this in your header.php file :

```
<header class="header clear <?php echo ((is_user_logged_in())?'logged-in-header':'not-logged-in-header'); ?>" role="banner">
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress actually adds an "logged-in" class to the body if the user is logged in.
So you can handle that for example with some CSS:

```
.logged-in #menu-item-123 {dispaly:none}
```

Could be a simple solution without touching any complex code.